# How can I change the background color of the column header not the text of the header facet in an apex:datatable

Tags: visualforce, dynamic-visualforce, dynamic-vf-component

I am trying below code in my 'apex:dataTable'.

```
<apex:dataTable value="{! Opportunity.Contract }" var="contract" styleClass="productsTable">
                
            <apex:column >
                
                <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value="Products" styleClass="rowHeaderWithGoldBackground"/></apex:facet>
                
                <apex:outputText value="{!contract.id}"/>
                <apex:facet name="footer"></apex:facet>
            </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in 'apex:dataTable' documentation available at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm that we can set the column header background color using the headerClass attribute of the dataTable. In my scenario I wrote a css class and referred it in the headerClass attribute. Below is my solution code.

```
<apex:dataTable value="{! Opportunity.Contract }" var="contract" styleClass="productsTable" headerClass="rowHeaderWithGoldBackground">
                
            <apex:column >
                
                <apex:facet name="header"> <apex:outputText value="Products"/></apex:facet>
                
                <apex:outputText value="{!contract.id}"/>
                <apex:facet name="footer"></apex:facet>
            </apex:column>
</apex:dataTable>
```

Thanks, I hope this will help the community!

Answer (score 0):

Please go through with the below code also you can add the style in apex:column tag.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" extensions="SetDataListPage" recordSetVar="accounts">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Viewing Accounts">
            <apex:dataTable value="{!accounts}" var="acc" width="60%" bgcolor="Cyan"  border="5%">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}" headervalue="Name" />
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Phone}" Headervalue="Phone" />
                <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Next}"/>
            </apex:dataTable>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!previous}">Previous</apex:commandLink>
                <apex:commandLink action="{!next}">Next</apex:commandLink>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Akshay Dhiman for sharing your solution, But this do not helped me in my case. As I want to change the background color of the column header not the entire column. I found a solution for that after reading the documentation for 'apex:dataTable', available at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_dataTable.htm. I am going to share it in the thread.